# How to update the names of tables and fields in a query inside php when the db is updated?

Tags: php, mysql

Which is the best way to organize the queries to the database, so that before any upgrade in the name of a table or the name of a field is not necessary to modify query by query in each of the php files?

I have over 100 php files each with specific and different queries to the database.

I have changed the names of some tables and fields on my db and now I realize I'll have to review over 100 php files to update the name of the table. I think there must be a better way!

Comment: Why would you change table fields when you have 100 php files??

Comment: most text editors have 'find and replace' functions built in

Comment: I have reorganized the names that were originally very poorly chosen, there was also a lack of consistency about tables and fields names. I know about the "find and replace", but I was wondering if there is a better way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is not such a thing you are expecting now. You may need to be ready to face when such a situation occurs.

I would suggest have a constants.php file which defined and contains all these constant values. then use those constant strings in your all php files. so you will have to edit one file called constants.php when face such a problem as you got now.

EX: constants.php file has:

```
define("TBL_USER", "users");
define("TBL_USER_CLM_ID", "id");
             .
             .
             .
```

for a better security, you can save this file above the web root and get it using `require_once();`

Comment: Thanks! Is this a common practice? On the other hand, this methodology would make slower queries?

Comment: I have seen good projects have done this. I don't have any reason to mention that this will make slow queries. after you get that constants.php by calling require_once() it will embed to your scripts. then use those values when calls

Answer (score 0):

You will face this problem over and over and bugs will appear every time, my suggestion is to  use an ORM like Eloquent, using relationships, accessors and scopes you can achieve this separation easily. You will have to change a lot but your code will be more isolated from DB naming convention.

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

http://www.edzynda.com/use-laravels-eloquent-orm-outside-of-laravel/